# Include horizontal line in Part title

Tags: memoir, titlesec

In a memoir document I have a Part that has a title and subtitle. I want to put the title and subtitle in different lines separated by a horizontal line.
With `\part*{TITLE\\[5ex] Subtitle}` I can separate both texts.
I can add a horizontal rule with `\part*{TITLE\\[5ex]\hrule{}{}{} Subtitle}` in which case the line is drawn but the text below is not separated from the line, if I try `\part*{TITLE\\[5ex]\hrule{}{}{}\\[5ex] Subtitle}` the compiler crashes, I get an error message "There's no line here to end", with option "s" the compiler continues and the line is drawn in the compiled document, nevertheless is there any way to get rid of the error message?

Comment: As always on this site plesae provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. That way it is a lot easier to see what you are doing and which preamble you are using. Note that `titlesec` should not be used with `memoir`

Comment: Note that the part title is given to other macros what might not expect a `\hrule`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\rule` with two arguments, width and thickness. Note that you need a space after the `\rule` command to push the subtitle to the next line. MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\part*{TITLE\\[5ex]\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} Subtitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to lower the subtitle you can use `\vskip`. Note that you don't need braces or a space for the argument.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\part*{TITLE\\[5ex]\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \vskip10mm Subtitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your example you used a `\part*` which is not printed in the Table of Contents. If you use a regular `\part` then it is a good idea to supply a short title without macros as optional argument, to prevent the macros to be used in the table of contents (or other places where the title is used, such as headers).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part[Title -- subtitle]{TITLE\\[5ex]\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \vskip10mm Subtitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *cheating* solution. We define a new macro and locally redefine what `\part`'s `\printparttitle` should do. Then run `\part*{}` as the redefined `\printparttitle` now have the title baked into it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\newcommand\DualPart[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont%
    #1\par\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\par#2\par%
  }%
  \part*{}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\DualPart{Title}{Subtitle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fine, thank for your help